# Switching databases in TG2 during runtime

Tags: python, sqlite, turbogears, turbogears2

I am doing an application which will use multiple sqlite3 databases, prepopuldated with data from an external application. Each database will have the exact same tables, but with different data.

I want to be able to switch between these databases according to user input. What is the most elegant way to do that in TurboGears 2?

Comment: Almost any other design is better than this.  Why can't you load a single database from multiple sources?

Comment: Or attach the external databases to your current one.  Which causes them to behave like they are in the same connection, just in a different namespace.

Comment: In order to load everything into one database, I would need to modify the schema, and I cannot do that as other applications depend on that schema. 

The ATTACH suggestion sounds interesting, but I can't think of a way to make it work in my case. I am relying on sqlalchemy to build my model declaratively, and each model class is associated with a tablename. To attach identical databases I will need to prepend each tablename with an identifier, which will break sqlalchemy.

Answer (score 1):

If ALL databases have the same schema then you should be able to create several Sessions using the same model to the different DBs.

Answer (score 1):

Dzhelil,

I wrote a blog post a while back about using multiple databases in TG2. You could combine this method with Jorge's suggestion of multiple DBSessions and I think you could do this easily.

[How to use multiple databases in TurboGears 2.0](http://blog.curiasolutions.com/?p=87)

Hope this helps, 
Seth

Answer (score 1):

I am using two databases for a read-only application. The second database is a cache in case the primary database is down. I use two objects to hold the connection, metadata and compatible `Table` instances. The top of the view function assigns `db = primary` or `db = secondary` and the rest is just queries against `db.tableA.join(db.tableB)`. I am not using the ORM.

The schemata are not strictly identical. The primary database needs a `schema.` prefix (`Table(...schema='schema')`) and the cache database does not. To get around this, I create my table objects in a function that takes the schema name as an argument. By calling the function once for each database, I wind up with compatible prefixed and non-prefixed `Table` objects.

At least in Pylons, the SQLAlchemy `meta.Session` is a `ScopedSession`. The application's `BaseController` in `appname/lib/base.py` calls `Session.remove()` after each request. It's probably better to have a single `Session` that talks to both databases, but if you don't you may need to modify your `BaseController` to call `.remove()` on each `Session`.